# Strong tires for Trek Verve 3

Tags: tire, trek

[image]I recently got a bargain on a Trek Verve 3 bike. From what I read, it should support my weight (6 feet tall, 290lbs and going down) if I get wider tires with strong sidewalls. Currently I have an AT 750 Rim with 700 x 32C tires and wonder what kind of tire I should get to ensure I will not get those flats on the road.

I will be using this bike for commuting on pavement only. No harsh riding or anything.

This bike also has the front suspension fork which I was told I could lock in to avoid it from going up and down all the time.

Any thoughts on the tires or advice at all? Thank you!

Comment: If you're not hot dogging then the only thing you really need to worry about is "snake bite" punctures from, eg, hitting a curb when your tire pressure is too low.  Keep tire pressure above about 70psi and you should have no troubles on a 32 or wider tire.  The only other thing you might do is get belted tires, to protect against ordinary punctures due to debris on the roadway.

Comment: Looking at the picture, though, it appears that the bike has no front brake.  That is not good, given your weight.  You should perhaps see if a bike shop will be able to install some used components at a reasonable price (or hit up a friend who has a basement full of old bike parts).

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback! The front tire has brakes, and yes I do need to replace those for a pair of new ones. I also need to clean it up, add some grease and change the brake cables. Will also buy a more "cushiony" saddle

Comment: BTW, I can't tell exactly what width rims you have, but from the picture I'd guess you should be able to safely use 35mm or 38mm tires on those rims (if you wish to have a wider tire).  Of course, you are also limited by the frame and how wide a tire you can install before it rubs.

Comment: How can I tell the width of the rim? I'm new at this whole bike thing. And when you say 35 or 38 mm tires, do you know where I can find those online? I been having a hard time finding them belted :(

Comment: The rim width is a bit hard to tell unless a sticker on the rim tells you (and even then the numbers are quite cryptic).  The important measurement is actually the *inside* width between the two sides, which, IIRC, should be at least 15mm or so for 35mm tires.  But "eyeballing" the rim it appears wider than mine, and I'm running 35mm tires with no difficulty

Comment: Its a relatively inexpensive hybrid which ships with 700x35 tires. So a 35 tire should be fine (probably 38 as well). Run at high pressure. I'd guess that your problem will be spokes if you take hits.

Comment: I'd stick marathon plus 35s on there, or 38s if they fit. They're as close to puncture proof as you can buy and (as they're meant for touring with heavy loads) designed to be run at higher pressures than similar sized tyres. This should eliminate snake bite flats. They're hard wearing so should outlast cheaper tyres. Other brands make similar tyres but these are what I know.

Comment: Eyeballing the photo, your seat is too low for a six foot person.  Look out for knee pain which is a sign of a low saddle.  Don't raise it above the minimum insertion line though.

Comment: @Criggie thank you for the heads up, I just had it down for the picture but definitely is too low for me like that

Comment: @ChrisH Thank you! Will definitely look for 38's, they should fit fine :)

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your statement "The front tire has brakes".  In the picture all I see is the brake bosses for the front wheel -- there are no brakes installed.  Do you mean that they had been removed for this picture or some such?

Answer (score 2):

There are many tire options available.

The Schwalbe Marathon Plus in. 700x35c, or the Specialized Armadillo tires in the same size will work for you needs.

The bike has other issues, though, including the mentioned missing brake.

It also appears to be small for someone 6 foot tall.

I would recommend having a good mechanic thoroughly check it over before riding it.